# Unable to update value in a form and send to next jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I have a form and trying to change a value in a hidden input element prior to submitting the data to another JSP file(db.jsp) for processing. Different value is stored depending on which button is clicked. But the change doesn't occur and the value is always sent over as the default value "abc" to the db.jsp file.

Form Page (index.jsp) and Javascript to change value depending on

```
<form method="post" action="db.jsp">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
        <button id="update" type="submit" >Update</button>
        <button id="delete" type="submit" >Delete</button>
        <input id="secret2" name="secret2" value="abc" type="hidden">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $("#delete").click(function(){
        //tried calling an alert here and no alert shows up. 
        document.getElementById("#secret2").value = "delete";
    });
    $("#update").click(function(){
        //tried calling an alert here and no alert shows up. 
        document.getElementById("#secret2").value = "update";
    });
</script>
```

db.jsp

```
<%
    String buttonId = request.getParameter("secret2");
    System.out.println(buttonId); //prints as "abc"
%>
```

**More Details on first Page Body (index.jsp):**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#delete").click(function(){
                document.getElementById("secret2").value = "delete";
            });
            $("#update").click(function(){
                document.getElementById("secret2").value = "update";
            });
        });
</script>
<body>
    <h1 class="k-h1-view-user">Users</h1>

    <%
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1:3306/db_name";
        String dbUser = "";
        String dbPass = "";
        Connection conn;

        try{
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset =
                    statement.executeQuery("select id, username, password, role from user");

            while(resultset.next()) {
    %>

    <form class="k-view-user-form k-form-margin-top" method="post" action="delete_user.jsp">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
            <input value="<%= resultset.getString(2) %>" type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameField" name="usernameField" placeholder="Username" style="margin: 0 auto">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
            <input value="<%= resultset.getString(3) %>" type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordField" name="passwordField" placeholder="Password" style="margin: 0 auto">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
            <select class="form-control" id="role" name="role" style="margin: 0 auto">
                <%
                    if(resultset.getString(4).equals("admin")){
                %>
                    <option value="admin" selected>Admin</option>
                    <option value="standard">Standard</option>
                <%
                    }
                    else{
                %>
                    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                    <option value="standard" selected>Standard</option>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
            <button id="update" type="submit" class="btn k-login-btn" style="float: left">Update</button>
            <button id="delete" type="submit" class="btn k-del-btn" style="float: right">Delete</button>
            <input name="secret" value="<%= resultset.getString(1) %>"  type="hidden">
            <input id="secret2" name="secret2" type="hidden">
        </div>
    </form>

    <%}

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    %>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using getElementById, don't use a hashtag selector, just use the straight up id.  Also don't do your bindings until the HTML is loaded, use $(document).ready()...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#delete").click(function(){
            document.getElementById("secret2").value = "delete";
        });
        $("#update").click(function(){
            document.getElementById("secret2").value = "update";
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue persists. Even an alert doesn't fire off when I call it inside the click function. The alert works outside the click function. It looks like the clicking is not recognized. My other JQuery functions are working so its not some JQuery link issue either.

Comment: @JasSy Ah, just put the event bindings into a document.ready block....  $( document ).ready(function() {});

Comment: Curious.  I got this exact code working in jsfiddle.  Two more things to try.  Depending on your document mode, this may be required on your script tag:  type="text/javascript"  Also, try an alert at the start of your script tag to ensure the script tag is loading.

Comment: You might also just need to show me a little bit more of the code. If there's a document.ready function wrapping those handlers, then I'm wondering what else I'm not seeing in your example.

Comment: The alert works when I use it at the start of script tag, I have added the code from the entire body of the first html page. Also added an image to show how that page is displayed for reference. Hope its clearer.

Comment: I just realized something. I am able to store the value correctly if I click the first update or delete button (The ones corresponding to name1). It doesn't register the value for the all other buttons.

Comment: So what does the HTML look like for the other buttons? I guess you're not using a generic enough selector to bind them all at once.

Comment: As you can see from the newly added code, each button is created in the while loop and each button is given the same id of either update or delete.

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone. If you use a jQuery selector to select by id, it only selects the first one. So now you have a slightly different problem, but easy enough to solve.

Comment: No prob. Thanks will look into other means of selecting such as name maybe.